# How to force Content Disposition Inline on JasperReports Server globally?

Tags: jasperserver

Testing the newer version of JasperReports Server Community 8.2.0. I noticed that Content-Disposition is set to attachment, however is it possible to set it to Inline? I tried making the change in applicationContext-webapp.xml but it still comes in as attachment. Any thoughts? An older version (6.0.1) did allowed to modify a java file but not sure how to achieve that with new version.

Changed applicationContext-webapp.xml from attachment to inline. But it still did not work.

`<bean p:method="GET" p:urlPattern="/fileview/fileview/.*" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.httpheaders.HeadersRule"> <property name="headers"> <list> <bean class="org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader"> <constructor-arg value="Content-Disposition"/> <constructor-arg value="**inline**"/> </bean> </list> </property> </bean>`